# Request get in java for get source html

Tags: java, html

I have this request in Java but in the response i haven't all source, and Json object fail..

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                 "http://url?"+params);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }


        String str = result.toString();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


        List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();


        Element elementsTable = doc.getElementById("shortlist");
```

this element shortlist can't find that..but if i go with my browser and get the source there is..where i'm wrong?

Comment: Please make your question more clear ?

Comment: i want the source from a url request. If i go in my browser and view the source it works i see the source and in the source there is a table with a id=shortlist. So i try in Java to get this source but not works in my way

Comment: this r variable nothing, i edit the question

Comment: Can you post the content that is actually returned by HTTPClient?

Comment: if i try System.out.println(str); i see in the output this element table with id shortlist, but doc.getElementById("shortlist"), not work..is possible?

Comment: @FelasDroid then you are not parsing the `JSON` correctly

Comment: ok thanks now i try to modify the parsing

Comment: the error is in the parsing

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with Jsoup with simpler code ...

```
 Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
 Document urlDoc = connection.get();
 Elements domElement = urlDoc.getElementById(String id);
```